# Write to Profile File After Installing PowerShell Module with PowerShellGet

Tags: powershell, deployment, powershell-5.0, powershellget

I have a custom PowerShell module with two cmdlets. I have it successfully, but manually, deployed on my machine. However, I deployed it by placing the binary file and module manifest in a location, and then registering the module. I also had to manually write an `Import-Module` command into my 'all users' profile.

Now I am sure I can deploy this module with `Publish-Module`, but how do I get the `Install-Module` to write the `Import-Module` statement to the profile file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of PowerShell 3.0, a module is automatically imported when a command from the module is invoked. This was a brilliant on Microsoft's part; however, it did require that modules are located in a location where PowerShell looks for modules by default. Makes sense. You can see those locations by running the following command:

```
$env:PSModulePath -split ';'
```

Is there a reason you'd rather not use one of the paths stored in the above environmental variable? That said, I'd keep your code *out* of the "C:\Windows\System32..." path. The other options are better: "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules" (AllUsers) and "C:\Users\tommymaynard\Documents\PowerShell\Modules" (CurrentUser). Depending on your PowerShell version/OS, those path could be different. You won't need to write an Import-Module command into a $PROFILE script if you get the module into a preferred location. Maybe you already know this, *but* maybe not.

You're not going to get Install-Module to write to any of the $PROFILE scripts.

```
$PROFILE | Select-Object -Property *
```

Well, not by default anyway. You could write your own Install-Module function, that runs PowerShellGet's Install-Module function, and includes writing to various $PROFILE scripts. The problem is that you'll need to include logic so you don't blow away the contents of someone's $PROFILE script if it's not empty, and only append to it.

Seriously though, this is turning into a lot of work, when you could drop the module into a location where PowerShell can find it on its own.

**Edit**: It just occurred to me, you can add a value/path to the $env:PSModulePath environmental variable. It's a single string with semi-colon delimiters:

```
$env:PSModulePath.GetType().Name
```

Therefore, it'd look like this:

```
$env:PSModulePath += ';C:\Another\Path'
```

That's great and all, but again how might you stage this, right? It takes you back to the write-to-all-the-$PROFILE-scripts problem,... although you may be able to update the variable via Group Policy Preferences. Again, probably better to just relocate your module.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I have since learned of the auto-import and abandoned the need to write an `Import-Module` anywhere.